# How can I multiple insert the data in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I want to insert multiple data in rails. I'm using postgresql, the scenario is when the form submit it passes client name, email and some personal info, then also pass the desire venue with the date and also the amenities they want (ex. swimming poll, billiard poll and etc.). In my backend I will query :

```
venue = Venue.find(theVenue_id)

book = venue.books.new(name: client_name, email: client_email and etc)
```

My question is how can I insert the data in my amenity_books if the had many amenities choosen?

I trie something like this.

```
ex. amenities_id_choosen = [1,3]
if book.save
   amenities_id_choosen.each do |x|
    amenity = Amenitiy.find(x)
    amenity_book = amenity.amenity_books.create(venue_id: venue.id)
end
```

I know this is not a good idea to insert data but that was my last choice. Does any body knows how to insert multiple data in 2 model with different data.

Models

```
class Amenity < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :venues, through: :categorizations

    has_many :amenity_books
    has_many :books, through: :amenity_books
end

class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :amenities, through: :categorizations
end

class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :venue
    belongs_to :amenity
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :venue
end

class AmenityBook < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :amenity
    belongs_to :venue
    belongs_to :book
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an improved version:

```
amenities_id_choosen = [1,3]

if book.save
  Amenitiy.find(amenities_id_choosen).each do |amenity|
    amenity.amenity_books.create(venue_id: venue.id)
  end
end
```

This will result in one SELECT query to find all chosen amenities and one INSERT query for each selected amenity.

---

Another option is to change your data model, does `AmenityBook` really need to have a venue? Because it looks like the venue is defined through the `Book` model already.

Here's a suggestion:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :venue
    has_many :amenity_books
    has_many :amenities, through: :amenity_books
end

class AmenityBook < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :amenity
    belongs_to :book
    has_one :venue, through: :book
end
```

The code to create a booking with many amenities:

```
amenities_id_choosen = [1,3]
book.amenity_ids = amenities_id_choosen

if book.save
  # success !
end
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Does any more improvement in my code? Is it ok to you do that in inserting data?

Comment: I added another suggestion, don't worry about performance too much - premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: `NoMethodError: undefined method `amenity_id='` I got an error. Should I loop the amenities_id?

Comment: It's plural `amenity_ids` and not `amenity_id`

Comment: I got it sir. I query those Id in Amenity `amenities = Amenity.where(id: [1,3])` then `book.amenities = amenities' next `book.save` then boom it saves. Thank you so much for this sir. Can I update my question sir and if ever you have suggestion for my next question it all about the book rooms in every venue.

Comment: No problem, it's better to accept an answer if it fits your need and create a new question.